# How do I get the list of files in the MUSIC folder on Android Q and above?

Tags: android, android-10.0, mediastore, android-music-player

I've been bringing up the list of files in the folder as below, but I can't use the method below in Android Q(Android 10) or higher.

How do I load a list of files in the MUSIC folder using MediaStore?

```
public void getFileListInFolder() {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    File directory = null;

    try {
        directory = new File(path);
        Log.i("debug","dir = " + directory);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("debug","Uri e = " + e);
    }

    File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isFile();
        }
    });

    if(files != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.i("debug", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated since Android Q

To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external
storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets
{@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q}, the path returned
from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps.
Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external
storage by migrating to alternatives such as
{@link Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)},
{@link MediaStore}, or {@link Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT}.

That means could not read/write file of /storage/emulated/0/Music directly,
but could read/write file under /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.youapp/files/Music

```
public void getFileListInFolder() {
    String path = getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d(TAG, "getFileListInFolder:path " + path);
    File directory = null;
    try {
        directory = new File(path);
        Log.i(TAG,"dir = " + directory);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"Uri e = " + e);
    }
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    Log.i(TAG, "getFileListInFolder:files " + files);
    for (File f:
         files) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getFileListInFolder: " + f.getName());
    }
    if(files != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```